# Get speed from distance time graph

Tags: derivatives

I have this distance time graph where I need to find the speed after 0s, 2s, 4s.
[image]

How would I proceed with this? I'm trying to learn derivatives, but I'm stuck here.

Comment: draw a tangent at each point and measure the gradient

Comment: As you can see I've tried doing it, but I'm not sure how would I be able to draw the 'right' tangent line. How can I get the slope right?

Comment: The speed (the derivative) is the slope of the tangent at the given points. If you need to approximate this graphically, you would draw the tangent first, then make a right triangle with it where you can estimate the slope as $\tan \phi$ of the angle $\phi$ between your tangent and the x axis.

Comment: you can only hope to get a rough estimate of the speed this way since you don't have the formula for the graph

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I've figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously a graphical construction cannot give an exact result. Anyway, as in the figure, If $A$ is a point of the $x$ axis and $B$ the corresponding point on the graph, take the tangent at $B$ than a point $C$ such that $\overline {CA}=1$, and take the  line parallel to the tangent from $C$, That intercepts $AB$ at $D$. $\overline {AD}$ is the value of the derivative of the function at $A$.
[image]